# Extracting power of a power law from data

Tags: distributions, fitting, computational-statistics, methodology, power-law

My question is more about the methodology. Assuming in some experiment we have measured quantity $y$ per each unit of time $x.$ So $y$ and $x$ form our data set here. Moreover, we know that they are related by a
power law type of relation, e.g., $y = D x^{\alpha},$ where $D$ is just a constant.

Now to extract $\alpha$ from the data-set, I know two ways:

- a) Calculating the logs of our data, we can then compute the derivative of the $\ln(y)$ w.r.t $\ln(x),$ so $\frac{d\ln y}{d\ln x}=\alpha$ and extract the power. One problem with this is that the sampling may not have been done logarithmically, so the spacings between the log'ed values are different. That means numerically it is going to be hard to accurately compute such derivative.
- b) Another way would be: taking the logs again as in above, but then we just fit the log'ed data with a line, the slope of which should give us an average $\alpha,$ right? Assuming this is correct, one problem is that if $\alpha$ is changing during different time scales of the experiment, the above fit wouldn't capture it. Maybe one could perform the fits piece-wise.

**Questions:**

- Have I laid out the above methods correctly? (e.g., is b) correct?)
- Does one method come more recommended or it really depends on the context? (*i.e.,* in view of the aforementioned difficulties) Finally, please feel free to suggest other ways of extracting $\alpha$ if you know of different methods, I'm very curious to find out.

(*If you prefer explaining your method with an example, I have created dummy data for purposes of illustration, here's [the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15yBmLVdPVNze-nWjfuuLYzsX0kVSKi9u), first column is $x$ and second column $y.$*)

---

**Clarifications upon reading discussions in the comment section:**

The aim here is only to tackle the problem of how to reasonably estimate (for instance by fitting) power laws that describe a given bivariate data set, and more precisely, finding power laws that correspond to each region of interest [*] (i.e., subsets of the data). With this in mind, what the [user Nick Cox has proposed as answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331178/extracting-power-of-a-power-law-from-data/331241#331241), is precisely on point.

[*]: thus e.g., fitting subsets of the data, and more contextually, looking for different power laws at different time-scales, because for instance from a physical point of view we expect the data to exhibit different power laws.

Comment: Another term for *a* is the tail index or exponent of the distribution. There are several approaches to its estimation. A good heuristic can be found in Gabaix's paper *Rank-1/2: A Simple Way to Improve the OLS Estimation of Tail Exponents* (http://www.nber.org/papers/t0342.pdf). More rigorous approaches include Hill's method and Pickand's method. Googling both will turn up many related papers. In addition googling 'filetype:pdf tail index estimation' will turn up many other alternatives.

Comment: Not for the first time, there seems to be danger of confusing quite different problems: (1) fitting a power function or power law to bivariate data and (2) fitting a power law (Pareto or Pareto-like) distribution to univariate data. What the problems have in common is the wording "power law" and the appearance of powers in two sets of equations. Your question seems to be about #1, in which case suggestions about #2 appear irrelevant, whatever their inherent interest. You seem to want to fit different power laws to different subsets of your data, but it's hard to be precise without examples.

Comment: @NickCox Dear Nick, very well captured, this is indeed what I am trying to learn to do (in terms of applications, e.g., in context of physics, this type of analysis is relevant when extracting different regime in the dynamics of a system, by measuring mean-squared-displacement of particles as function of time, and seeing what power-law governs the MSD during which time scales). Sure, I will generate dummy data that can be utilized to illustrate here.

Comment: @NickCox the power-law changes at different time scales, e.g., during the first decades (of sampling) it shows diffusion, meaning ($y\propto x^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha = 1$) and later may become sub-diffusive, so $\alpha$ coverging to smaller than $1$ values. By the way, I've edited and added example data.

Comment: Thinking in relative proportionate terms works for both uni- and bivariate models. Psychologists speak of two 'types' of cognitive function: lumpers and splitters. The risks of the former are that gross differences are blurred while the risks of the latter are that hairs are split or purely pedantic distinctions are made. Reconciling this binary opposition is, for practical purposes, impossible. Another way of stating this is, after Gumbel, "A (statement) can have either intelligibility or correctness. To combine the two is impossible." Splitters will find this remark a nonsequitur (again)

Comment: @DJohnson Sorry, but I think you misread the question in your enthusiasm to link to one of your top interests. The OP has confirmed that. You might as well say that all questions in which logarithms are mentioned or implied are the same question.  Gumbel was there just copying from Russell, but failing to cite him, incidentally

Comment: @nickcox  You've misread the intent of my original comment. The OP *liked* the suggestion of the tail exponent as an intuitive heuristic, *period*. Any effort at gainsaying that is, quite simply, inappropriate, misguided and wrong. Given such a basic, foundational understanding at the univariate level it is a trivial extension to go to the bivariate case, as you suggest.

Comment: @DJohnson There is no sense whatsoever in which e.g. the analysis in my answer is an extension of the theory for univariate distributions you point to. I think you're just confusing an otherwise well-focused thread: the first paragraph of the original question is crystal clear on what the problem is, and that is reinforced by the OP's comment on the other answer to underline the distinction. I  am happy to let readers decide on whatever  they find here that is focused, interesting and helpful.

Comment: @DJohnson  We don't expect to convince each other, but I do care that other people can be misled by error, confusion and irrelevance. These comments aren't pertinent or even factual: power functions aren't nonlinear exponential  models; they go back at least to the 18th century; nor are they univariate processes, whatever that means. Marginal and even conditional distributions don't need to be considered to apply the analysis in my answer.

Comment: Power functions $y = ax^b$ as are discussed in this thread (except in your comments) are not S-shaped. They are convex or concave curves in $(x, y)$ space and straight lines in $(\log x, \log y)$ space.

Comment: @NickCox what is going on in these discussions? :( I hope I didn't cause this fight...

Comment: @user929304 No; you're entirely innocent.  Thanks for accepting my answer.  I won't try to summarize the disagreement between DJohnson and myself, for reasons obvious and not so obvious.  You can comment, or not, entirely as you please.

Comment: User929304 Comments mean much less on this site than do actual answers.  When two (or more) people seem to be disputing matters of fact or art in comments, and one of them does not post an actual answer and resorts to *ad hominem* arguments (which are never appropriate here), then it is always a good idea to treat their position sceptically. As @Nick has suggested, such disputes can arise from different readings of the original question, so edits to clarify it are always welcome.

Comment: @whuber Couldn't agree more. I've edited the post to provide more definite clarifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in my first comment on the question I see this as being entirely about power laws for bivariate data. (The inclination to read it otherwise is puzzling.)

Based on the posted data, I did local polynomial smoothing; the choices here are no more than not very smart defaults in the program used, but equally there doesn't seem much need to play with other choices. (The $R^2$ here is just the square of the correlation between observed and smoothed; 1 isn't even a target as interpolating the data could achieve that.)

[image]

It seems clear that the slope stabilises fairly quickly and systematically in logarithmic space, so that numerical differentiation could give you estimates of slope as it changes.

Comment: Thank you for performing the test, I don't know what fit function you have used (or what program), but I have tried taking the derivative of this sample data (in log space) in python and it's fluctuating all over the place so to speak... it may be my method in python is not appropriate (I've simply used `np.gradient(np.log(y))/np.gradient(np.log(x))` `np` standing for `numpy` here. It would be interesting to see how the derivative turns out with your program if you could kindly check.

Comment: As said, this is local polynomial smoothing; there is no global function, just linear regression within moving windows and with weights within the window. I imagine that, as I should have emphasised, you have to smooth first because numeric differentiation is sensitive to local noise. I'm calling up `lpoly` in Stata documented at https://www.stata.com/manuals/rlpoly.pdf except that I am calling it through my own program which just chooses different defaults. Conversely, sorry, but I don't use python and can't advise on how to do it. Presumably, there will be implementations to choose from.

Comment: Alright, fair enough. If you find the time to perform the derivative in your program, let me know please how it turns out, it would be a sanity check for me that I'm doing things correctly in python.

Comment: I get final slopes about 0.3.

Answer (score 4):

*Edit: The question is actually about data in which $x$ and $y$ are allowed to vary. This answer is not relevant to that case, but only to the case when $x$ is a quantity and you want to fit a distribution of the form $f(x) \propto x^{\alpha}$ to it. However, I am leaving it up because it links to a paper which is state-of-the-art for this case, which may be useful for some readers who are confused (like I was) by the question title.*

I suggest reading the [following paper by Clauset, Shalizi and Newman](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062). It recommends using maximum likelihood to fit a power law (so, not taking logs and fitting a straight line at all).

Even if you *know* that the data follow a power law and you are just trying to find an exponent, it might still not be appropriate to fit a straight line to the log-log plot with least squares. This is because, if you fit such a line, any statistical calculations are implicitly assuming that the errors in measuring $\log(y)$ are normally distributed, which may not be true, depending on circumstances. See Appendix A of the above paper.

Comment: Very interesting! thanks a lot for bringing this paper to my attention. I wonder, for Appendix A, isn't the case being discussed only of relevant for when the lhs is a probability distribution?

Comment: This is a very good paper, & always worth a read. However, note that it pertains to a *univariate* power law distribution, not a *bivariate* power law relationship. This is the point @NickCox was trying to bring out.

Comment: Yes, I understand the point but was not sure whether to delete my answer, since the OP seemed to find it useful.

Comment: I'd say: keep your answer. First, the _title_ of the thread may make it entirely relevant to some readers. Second, it should now be clear to careful readers of the thread what is what.